# Strange crash in for loop

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a for loop in my Swift app - iterating through an array - pretty standard. For some reason, for the past day, its been giving me an index out of bounds exception.

If there are 10 items in the array, when I iterate through the array to debug, it runs alright for the first 9 items (index = 0 to 8). But on the last iteration, I get an error saying

`Index 10 is out of bounds (must be less than 10)`

I have no idea why it misses index 9, goes straight to 10. Tried restarting Xcode and my laptop but the error still remains.

```
for object in articles {
    //do something here with object
}
```

**EDIT**
For anyone interested, this was because `++` is deprecated in Swift now and the custom enumerator was using it for iterating through the results. A quick update fixed this.

Comment: Are you sure `articles` is not modified somewhere in the code, maybe by a different thread? These kind of things are easy to slip through.

Comment: What's in it? With a "classic for loop" with index instead of a "for each" , it still crashes? Do you modify `articles` ?

Comment: No it isn't. I actually logged the count of `articles` on each iteration out of frustration to understand what was wrong. I don't modify `articles` anywhere, just consume the values. And it ONLY happens on the last iteration

Comment: Can you compose a full example that will demonstrate your issue?

Comment: nvm, looks like this issue is isolated to the library I am using to create the array. It has a custom enumerator. Thanks again.